Showframe package conflicts with SyncTeX
When using the showframe package, SyncTeX jumps to source code are messed up. Instead of jumping to the correct line, the jumps usually point to the end of a page / float.
MWE:
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
Hier steht ein Text \\
und hier noch mehr Text \\
auch hier wieder Text \\
und noch mehr Text \newpage
Auch hier steht Text \\
wieder mehr Text \\
ebenso noch mehr Text \\
immer mehr Text
\end{document}

I'm using the latest TeXMaker 6.0.0 with MiKTeX 4.12. My compiler settings are the following:

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex

Removing the showframe package solves the issue, so my guess is that there's a bug in the source code.
As I've no idea how to program in LaTeX myself, is there someone that could have a look at it and maybe figure out the reason for the issue?
Edit: I figured out that the \AddToShipoutPictureFG command is responsible for the issue. Although I've not found a solution how to fix it yet. Is anyone able to help fix this?
Thanks in advance for your help and time!

your example works fine here. It is not enough to tell the texmaker and miktex console version, important are also the version of showframe/eso-pic and of the pdftex engine. You find these data in the log-file.

@UlrikeFischer That's the content of the log file resulting from my MWE:
https://pastebin.com/6s4D6rPs

looks current. Not sure if it is related but you are using bitmap fonts: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\ecrm
1200.pk. Install the cm-super package.

I just installed the cm-super package, but the issue persists. I wonder, why it's not replicable for you... If it helps, I postet a video demonstrating it on the eso-pic github: Github Issue

I can not reproduce it with the pdf viewer of my editor (winedt), but with sumatra if fails. You could test with winedt too https://www.winedt.com/download.html and if it works ask their support https://github.com/WinEdt-Team/WinEdt-Support what they are doing differently ...

My issue occurs in TeXMaker and TeXworks, but not in WinEdt. The SyncTeX files are identical on all three - with the only difference being that WinEdt directly outputs the .synctex file, while it is packed into a .synctex.gz archive which contains the .synctex file when using TeXMaker or TeXworks...

Hope it related with the version issue, please update the TeX installation and try

@MadyYuvi My TeX installation - so all my packages - are up to date. The issue is fundamentally embedded into the eso-pic / showframe package. Any idea how one could modify these in order to get SyncTeX to work properly again?

@NeverGameStar Sorry, no idea, hence your MWE is working fine for me

What version of TeXMaker are you using, if I may ask?
